# Getting Error while installing psycopg2 in windows

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Hi I am working on a Django project and I am getting errors while installing psycopg2 on windows

```
pip install psycopg2
```

I also tried

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

but still getting error

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\theuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\theuser\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zh83zqbg\\psycopg2\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\theuser\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zh83zqbg\\psycopg2\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\theuser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-upmu4r_j'
     cwd: C:\Users\theuser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zh83zqbg\psycopg2\
Complete output (23 lines):
running egg_info
creating C:\Users\theuser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-upmu4r_j\psycopg2.egg-info
writing C:\Users\theuser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-upmu4r_j\psycopg2.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to C:\Users\theuser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-upmu4r_j\psycopg2.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to C:\Users\theuser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-upmu4r_j\psycopg2.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing manifest file 'C:\Users\theuser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-upmu4r_j\psycopg2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'

Error: pg_config executable not found.

pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
option:

    python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
<https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).

----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is this:

```
Error: pg_config executable not found.
```

Either you didn't install the development tools (`pg_config` belongs to them), or the directory where the executable is installed is not in your `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have postgres installed on windows